# php file() into foreach - Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 1 level

Tags: php

im using a file() function to read a remote file containing ips and place into an array for it to be checked against $_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR];. However Once its read and processed, i get a Fatal error message!

**Code**

```
$url = 'http://v87145.hosted-by-vdsina.ru/cUrl/blacklisted.dat';
$ip_block = file($url);

if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])) {
$client_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
}

$blocked = false;
foreach($ip_block as $ip)
echo $ip . "<br/>\n"; //just to verify file has been read

{
        if($client_ip == $ip)
        {
            $blocked = true;
            break;
        }else if(strpos($ip, '*') !== false){
            $digits = explode(".", $ip);
            $client_ip_digits = explode(".", $client_ip);
            if($digits[1] == '*' && $digits[0] == $client_ip_digits[0])
            {
                $blocked = true;
                break;
            }else if($digits[2] == '*' && $digits[0] == $client_ip_digits[0] && $digits[1] == $client_ip_digits[1]){
                $blocked = true;
                break;
            }else if($digits[3] == '*' && $digits[0] == $client_ip_digits[0] && $digits[1] == $client_ip_digits[1] && $digits[2] == $client_ip_digits[2]){
                $blocked = true;
                break;
            }
        }else if(strpos($ip, "-") !== false){
            list($start_ip, $end_ip) = explode("-", $ip);
            $start_ip = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $start_ip);
            $end_ip = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $end_ip);
            $client_ip_long = ip2long($ip);     
            $start_ip_long = ip2long($start_ip);
            $end_ip_long = ip2long($end_ip);
            if($client_ip_long >= $start_ip_long && $client_ip_long <= $end_ip_long)
            {
                $blocked = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

if($blocked == true)
{
    # header('HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found');
    # die;
    echo $ip . ' is blocked' . "<br />\n";
}
```

The error message im getting is: **Fatal error: Cannot break/continue 1 level in /home/admin/web/*****/public_html/check_me.php on line 30**

What could possibly be wrong? if i just make a simple **array()** it works fine, so while is **file()** producing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The placement of your `echo` statement is separating your `foreach` statement from its body code block, causing your `break` statements to try to break out of a code block that's not part of a loop.

Code blocks are optional for conditionals (`if`/`else`) and loops (`for`/`while`/`do`/`foreach`). If those statements are not followed by a code block, PHP will execute the next command it sees.

Additionally, you can have code blocks anywhere in PHP, which is why your code doesn't give a syntax error.

Your current code:

```
foreach($ip_block as $ip)
echo $ip . "<br/>\n"; //just to verify file has been read

{
    if($client_ip == $ip)
    {
        $blocked = true;
        break;
    }
    // [...]
}
```

Is basically the same as:

```
foreach($ip_block as $ip) {
    echo $ip . "<br/>\n"; //just to verify file has been read
}

{
    if($client_ip == $ip)
    {
        $blocked = true;
        break;
    }
    // [...]
}
```

Since that second code block is, from PHP's point of view, not part of the `foreach` body, your `break` statement makes no sense.

You can fix this easily by moving your `echo` statement after that `{`, making it part of the `foreach` body code block:

```
foreach($ip_block as $ip)
{
    echo $ip . "<br/>\n"; //just to verify file has been read

    if($client_ip == $ip)
    {
        $blocked = true;
        break;
    }
    [...]
}
```

Comment: This should be closed as off topic for typos.

Comment: @rickdenhaan this solution worked perfectly and explanation made so much sense. Much appreciated!